# How to change IOS speak recognition language?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, speech-recognition

I'm implementing the speech recognition in my ios app using this code (xamarin):

```
// Setup audio session
        var node = AudioEngine.InputNode;
        var recordingFormat = node.GetBusOutputFormat (0);
        node.InstallTapOnBus (0, 1024, recordingFormat, (AVAudioPcmBuffer buffer, AVAudioTime when) => {
            // Append buffer to recognition request
            LiveSpeechRequest.Append (buffer);
        });

        // Start recording
        AudioEngine.Prepare ();
        NSError error;
        AudioEngine.StartAndReturnError (out error);

        // Did recording start?
        if (error != null) {
            // Handle error and return
            return;
        }

        // Start recognition
        RecognitionTask = SpeechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask (LiveSpeechRequest, (SFSpeechRecognitionResult result, NSError err) => {
            // Was there an error?
            if (err != null) {
                // Handle error
            } else {
                // Is this the final translation?
                //if (result.Final) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("You said \"{0}\".", result.BestTranscription.FormattedString);
                //}
            }
        });
```

It works very well except that french is not recognized, I put my phone in french but it doesn't work. Is there a argument to set somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found that the "locale" can be defined when initializing the `SpeechRecognizer` object, like that:

```
private SFSpeechRecognizer SpeechRecognizer = new SFSpeechRecognizer (new NSLocale ("fr_FR"));
```

It works !